# Remove button over a button Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I am coding the functionality of a button that serves to remove other buttons. My buttons are dynamic. I have to program the functionality in my .kt. I am noob on android studio so am not sure what the best way to do it.

The function is like this:

[image]

I have a TableRow where are my buttons. All this buttons have their own listener.

```
val param: TableRow.LayoutParams =TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

var buttondynamic = Button(this)
buttondynamic = buildButton(item, i, mysize, mysize, true)

buttondynamic.layoutParams = param
tr.addView(buttondynamic)
```

Also I have a listener for the trash button but I don't know how to make the action works. How I should code this? Hove you some idea?

```
trashButton.setOnClickListener {
      // This for goes over the table taking every single button
      for(i in 1..12){
            val btnFor: Button = findViewById(i) as Button
            ... -> here the codo shoul be (I think)
      }
}
```

On the other hand, I have the code for the delete button listener. I only need the idia for the remove button over a button.

Thank you so much

Comment: sounds like you just need a recyclerview or a gridview perhaps, instead of doing everything dynamically

Comment: Yes, but this is not all my code so I need use these... I don't know if it is posible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it for just the current view , mean that you want it to appear the next time you open that activity , so just set its visibility like :

```
button.Visiblity = View.GONE
```

But if that buttons is connected to some stored data , like an array or a list or something like that , you can just delete that stored data for that button and reload your table again .

Comment: Thank you! How can I reload the table from a listener?